# How to run a CodeIgniter file through CRON?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I've tried the following method in the past:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = 'cron/controller/index';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'cron/controller/index';
require_once('index.php');
?>
```

and putting this in a file in the codeigniter installation directory, calling it cron.php, and then invoking it via:

```
php /home/[username]/public_html/my_project/cron.php
```

If I type the URL to cron.php in my browser it works perfectly, however whenever its run via CRON I get a 404 error. Putting the following code in the `show_404()` function of CodeIgniter

```
function show_404($page = '')
{
   print_r($_SERVER);
   echo "\n\n";
   die ($page);
}
```

results in getting the following output emailed to me:

```
Array
(
   [SHELL] => /bin/sh
   [MAILTO] => me@gmail.com
   [USER] => [me]
   [PATH] => /usr/bin:/bin
   [PWD] => /home/[me]
   [SHLVL] => 1
   [HOME] => /home/[me]
   [LOGNAME] => [me]
   [_] => /usr/bin/php
   [PHP_SELF] =>
   [REQUEST_TIME] => 1266479641
   [argv] => Array
       (
           [0] => /home/[me]/public_html/my_project/cron.php
       )

   [argc] => 1
   [PATH_INFO] => cron/controller/index
   [REQUEST_URI] => cron/controllers/index
)


home/[me]
```

Here I've [me] in place of my actual username.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this post - https://glennstovall.com/writing-cron-job-in-codeigniter/. Running very frequent calls can become taxing if you start to do a wget or a curl every minute. The general syntax is <path to php eg. /usr/bin/php> <path to codeigniter project>/index.php <controller name>/<function_name> Eg php /home/<your_domain>/public_html/<your_subdomain>/index.php cron/clear_unpaid_requests

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way to run a cron via CodeIgniter is to make a cron URL available via your app.

Then call it via wget

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron/run
```

Inside the controller you can then use a log to ensure the cron is not run too often i.e. if the Google robots trigger it by mistake.

A second method would be to use lynx

```
/usr/local/bin/lynx -source http://www.example.com/cron/run
```

Comment: With w get do i need to copy the asteriks as well? Should I copy the entire command as you give it?

Comment: The asterisks relate to when the cron is run. I *think* the ones I quoted were to run the cron every hour.

Comment: Cool. I was using the cpanel interface to add the cron job so I didn't need the asteriks. Cheers

Comment: it will not use the CLI, which is not the best idea if you are limited by apache timeout. if you have a script that needs to run for a long time, use the bootstrapper

Comment: the problem with this method is now your script is accessible from the web. and usually something run via cron is a private script. look into  `$this->input->is_cli_request()`. you should be able to call your cron scripts with `php $HOME/path/to/script/index.php controller method param`

Answer (score 5):

You may also like to add --spider to ignore the response. This stops the request from timing out:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 --spider http://www.example.com/cron/run
```

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to check this out: [Cron job bootstrapper](https://github.com/compwright/codeigniter-cli-bootstrap)

> This is a simple bootstrapper file that you can use to directly run your CodeIgniter controllers from the commandline. It’s a very easy and elegant solution for using CI controllers for cron jobs. It also supports logging.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wiki article about how to run CodeIgniter on the command line, but this is more useful for applications that need to interact with the user through terminal (there's a library for that too).

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CI_on_the_command_line/

One benefit of doing it this way over using wget is you can protect your code from being run by users or bots with:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
{
     show_error('Shove off hax0r!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run cron job by running url, here is a great article

http://www.nbill.co.uk/documentation/setting-up-a-cronjob.html

Answer (score 0):

Use php-cli instead of php
Ex:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli  /home/CPANEL_USER/public_html/index.php cronJobs deleteNotifications
```