# Why does the codeigniter cron not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to set up cronjob `in codeIgniter on my localhost` so that when I run the same path from terminal it works

This is the Path I have run from the cli(terminal):

```
/usr/bin/php /home/user_name/path_to_index.php users foo
```

this works

but when I set this in the crontab file as :

```
 3 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /home/user_name/path_to_index.php users foo
```

this is not working.

any idea what is wrong here?

thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked /var/log/syslog?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287070/how-to-run-a-codeigniter-file-through-cron link. think it will help you

Comment: @steven yes it has nothing about the cron

Comment: @steven I just restarted the system & saw the /var/log/syslog file it says :    

Aug  9 19:50:01 ivb-desktop cron[898]: (ivb) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/ivb)
Aug  9 19:50:01 ivb-desktop cron[898]: (ivb~) ORPHAN (no passwd entry)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/usr/bin/curl http://examblewebsite/index.php/front/cronjob
```

`front` - Controller name

`cronjob` - function name

in your localhost

```
0 13 * * * php [application_path]/index.php cli/reminders
```

if you have more details see this [link](http://glennstovall.com/blog/2013/01/07/writing-cron-jobs-and-command-line-scripts-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: I am trying cronjob on localhost

Answer (score 0):

If the default method you tried is not working you can make a call through http protocol.

```
wget http://example.com/example/test/bar/
```

or

```
curl http://example.com/example/test/bar/
```

Reference: http://mildcoder.com/handling-codeigniter-in-cli-and-cron-jobs/